# How to create VNodes from a string with html tags in Vue 2.5?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create a functional component that renders the Feather Icons package but I'm not able to figure out the last step. Here's what I got:

This is my **FeatherIcon.vue** component.

```
<script>
const feather = require("feather-icons");

export default {
  components: {},
  props: {
    type: {
      required: true,
      type: String
    }
  },
  mounted() {},
  render(createElement) {
    return createElement(
      "svg",
      {attrs: feather.icons[this.type].attrs },
      feather.icons[this.type].contents
    );
  }
};
</script>
```

The 3rd argument according to Vue docs says that it should be either:

```
// {String | Array}
// Children VNodes, built using `createElement()`,
// or using strings to get 'text VNodes'. Optional.
```

However, the result of my 3rd argument **feather.icon[this.type].contents** is a string containing the "innerHTML" inside the svg tag:

```
"<line x1="6" y1="3" x2="6" y2="15"></line><circle cx="18" cy="6" r="3"></circle><circle cx="6" cy="18" r="3"></circle><path d="M18 9a9 9 0 0 1-9 9"></path>"
```

So my question is, how to convert **feather.icon[this.type].contents** into a set of VNodes?

I've tried with DOMParser and using parseFromString but no luck. Any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `domProps` property of [the data object](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth).

> This object also allows you to bind normal HTML attributes as well as
> DOM properties such as innerHTML (this would replace the v-html
> directive)

Here is an example.

```js
console.clear()

const content = `
  <line x1="6" y1="3" x2="6" y2="15"></line>
  <circle cx="18" cy="6" r="3"></circle>
  <circle cx="6" cy="18" r="3"></circle>
  <path d="M18 9a9 9 0 0 1-9 9"></path>
`

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  render(h){
    return h("svg", {domProps:{innerHTML: content}})
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

In your case, you would just set innerHTML to the content from feathers.

Also, as a side note, if you don't have a template, generally you just use a straight javascript file. You don't need a single file component. So your component would be

**FeatherIcon.js**

```
const feather = require("feather-icons");

export default {
  props: {
    type: {
      required: true,
      type: String
    }
  },
  render(createElement) {
    return createElement(
      "svg",
      {
        attrs: feather.icons[this.type].attrs,
        domProps: {
          innerHTML: feather.icons[this.type].content
        }
      });
  }
};
```

Finally, you mentioned wanted to make this a functional component, in which case, you could just do something like this:

```
const FeatherIcon = {
  functional: true,
  props: {
    type: {
      required: true,
      type: String
    }
  },
  render(h, context){
    const {contents, attrs} = feather.icons[context.props.type]
    return h("svg", {attrs, domProps: {innerHTML: contents}})
  }
};
```

Here is an example of that working.

```js
console.clear()

const FeatherIcon = {
  functional: true,
  props: {
    type: {
      required: true,
      type: String
    }
  },
  render(h, context){
    const {contents, attrs} = feather.icons[context.props.type]
    return h("svg", {attrs, domProps: {innerHTML: contents}})
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    FeatherIcon
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons"></script>
<div id="app">
  <feather-icon type="eye"></feather-icon>
  <feather-icon type="activity"></feather-icon>
  <feather-icon type="award"></feather-icon>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thanks! I will edit my original question that had a typo. Should be "contents" instead "content" as I typed. I've tried the domProps approach as well but wasn't working because of this.